# Dot syntax causes 200x slowdown with vector addition

Tags: julia, vectorization

I was experimenting with the speed of vector addition and component-wise exponentiation, when I came across a strange result with the [dot vectorization syntax.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1)

The **non-vectorized** version,

```
julia> @time exp(randn(1000) + randn(1000))
```

takes about 0.001 seconds after a few runs. It also gives a deprecation warning as of 0.6.

If I vectorize the **exponential** function,

```
julia> @time exp.(randn(1000) + randn(1000))
```

I get a 4x speedup, to around 0.00025 seconds.

However, if I vectorize **both** the exponential function and addition of the vectors,

```
julia> @time exp.(randn(1000) .+ randn(1000))
```

I get a large slowdown to around 0.05 seconds. Why does this occur? When should the dot syntax be avoided to maximize performance?

Comment: The reason of the difference is probably precompilation. Try using `@benchmark` macro from `BenchmarkTools.jl` to get a clean comparison. I have checked the codes both under Julia 0.6 and Julia 0.7 and they have very similar timing. The difference is that: a) version without `.` allocates an additional vector that is passed to `exp`, b) version with `.` fuses addition and exponentiation thus it allocates roughly two times less memory. For vector of size `10^6` the version with `.` is noticeably faster than the version without `.` because of this difference.

Answer (score 1):

`.+` creates an anonymous function. In the REPL, this function is created every time and will blow up your timing results. In addition, the use of global (dynamically typed, i.e. uninferrable) slow down all of your examples. In any real case your code will be in a function. When it's in a function, it's only compiled the first time the function is called. Example:

```
> x = randn(1000); y = randn(1000);

> @time exp(x + y);
WARNING: exp(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T <: Number is deprecated, use exp.(x) instead.
Stacktrace:
 [1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at .\deprecated.jl:70
 [2] exp(::Array{Float64,1}) at .\deprecated.jl:57
 [3] eval(::Module, ::Any) at .\boot.jl:235
 [4] eval_user_input(::Any, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackend) at .\REPL.jl:66
 [5] macro expansion at C:\Users\Chris\.julia\v0.6\Revise\src\Revise.jl:775 [inlined]
 [6] (::Revise.##17#18{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at .\event.jl:73
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 237
  0.620712 seconds (290.34 k allocations: 15.150 MiB)

> @time exp(x + y);
  0.023072 seconds (27.09 k allocations: 1.417 MiB)

> @time exp(x + y);
  0.000334 seconds (95 allocations: 27.938 KiB)

>

> @time exp.(x .+ y);
  1.764459 seconds (735.52 k allocations: 39.169 MiB, 0.80% gc time)

> @time exp.(x .+ y);
  0.017914 seconds (5.92 k allocations: 328.978 KiB)

> @time exp.(x .+ y);
  0.017853 seconds (5.92 k allocations: 328.509 KiB)

>

> f(x,y) = exp.(x .+ y);

> @time f(x,y);
  0.022357 seconds (21.59 k allocations: 959.157 KiB)

> @time f(x,y);
  0.000020 seconds (5 allocations: 8.094 KiB)

> @time f(x,y);
  0.000021 seconds (5 allocations: 8.094 KiB)
```

Notice that by putting it into a function it compiles and optimizes. This is one of the main things mentioned in the [Julia Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/manual/performance-tips/).